# Magento 1 : How to add multiple route in single Module

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1

Below is the code for the router in config.xml

```
<routers>
    <representatives>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Mage_Representatives</module>
            <frontName>dealer-questionnaire</frontName>
        </args>
    </representatives>
</routers>
```

I want to add one more route in this module how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do you just need to add your additional routes like so

```
    <routers>
        <representatives>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mage_Representatives</module>
                <frontName>dealer-questionnaire</frontName>
            </args>
        </representatives>
        <representatives_new>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mage_Representatives</module>
                <frontName>dealer-questionnaire_new</frontName>
            </args>
        </representatives_new>
    </routers>
```

Comment: How can I add template to that route? my current layout file looks like this.
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <representatives_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="representatives.form" as="brochure_form" template="representatives/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </representatives_index_index>
</layout>`

Comment: im assuming this is what you are asking for. <representatives_new_index_index>

Comment: Do I have to create differenct also for that?

Comment: Yes new controller and new layout file

Comment: Thanks . its working now.